# Crear cuenta regresiva N segundos mientras se visualiza una Activity en Android

Tags: java, android

Quiero implementar una cuenta regresiva de N segundos, que se inicie cuando la `Activity` se muestre, se pare el contador cuando el usuario decide cambiar de app y se vuelve a reanudar cuando se vuelve a tener foco.

Se deben detectar eventos para poder lanzar procedimentos cuando

- cada cambio de segundo
- cuando llega a 0

y una función para saber si el contador está en funcionamiento.

Mi idea es implementar un sistema de visualización de publicidad a pantalla completa, que se requiere de visualizarla N segundos.

Comment: Esa respuesta de SO puede servirme de referencia http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550561/pause-the-timer-and-then-continue-it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probablemente sea viejo (lo usé en una app hace un par de años) y tengas algo mejor pero si te sirve como base esto me ha funcionado.

Sobre la clase que extiende [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) debes implementar dos métodos solamente.
Luego desde la actividad donde lo llames con algo similar a

```
final MiContador timer = new MiContador(30000,1000);
timer.start();


public class MiContador extends CountDownTimer{

    public MiContador(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
    //Lo que quieras hacer al finalizar

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {          
        //texto a mostrar en cuenta regresiva en un textview
        countdownText.setText((millisUntilFinished/1000+""));

    }
}
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Si que me ha servido

Answer (score 1):

Adaptando la respuesta de @tinoper para que el contador se pare cuando se pierde el `foreground`de la `Activity` y se renueve la cuenta regresiva cuando vuelve a pasar en primer plano

**Variables globales**

```
private MiContador timer;
private long lastCountDown = 30000; //Milliseconds for view ad
private Boolean isCountDown = false;
```

**en onResume()**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    Log.i(TAG, "onResume: ");
    timer  = new MiContador(lastCountDown, 1000);
    timer.start();

}
```

**en onPause()**

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    timer.cancel();
    Log.i(TAG, "onPause: ");
    super.onPause();

}
```

**Clase MiContador** extendido de `CountDownTimer`

```
public class MiContador extends CountDownTimer {
    private final String TAG = MiContador.class.getSimpleName();
    public MiContador(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        isCountDown = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onFinish: ");
        isCountDown = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTick: " + String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000));
        lastCountDown = millisUntilFinished;
        //countdownText.setText((millisUntilFinished / 1000 + ""));

    }
}
```